# How to send Push Notification from one iPhone Device to another?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, push-notification

Is it possible to send Push Notification from one iPhone Device to another?

If yes, then can you please show me how it can be done?

Comment: this question is very broad.Yes we can send push notifications from one device to another.For that read push notification tutorial.

Comment: try this link:-http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/programming-apple-push-notification-services

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, you can not send Push Notifications directly between two devices. Push notifications are sent from a dedicated server that you own or have hosted by somebody else.

If you want to trigger a push notification from one phone to another then you need to implement a system where the first phone sends a message to your server which then sends the notification to the other phone.

From a users perspective it will work like they send it directly, but technically it's a bit more complicated.

Comment: I don't see any problem to send push-notifications directly to APNS from iOS. Yes, it will be not safe to store master key and certificate, but it is possible..

Comment: @Nekto this was not how Apple want it designed and certainly won't like the many non persistent connections!!!  Claus is spot on though

Comment: Though you tecnically may be able to pull this one off on a true device-to-device basis there are a number of issues that would most likely cause your service to be terminated by Apple: For instance persistant connections from the push provider to avoid being flagged as DoS attack. Installation of your private certificate on the device (good luck in protecting that). Apple consistenly refer to the provider as being on a server... Etc. etc.